# Why can characters walk/run on space ships in Gundam?

Tags: spaceship, artificial-gravity, mobile-suit-gundam

I was watching Zeta and realized that characters seem to walk or even run around fine for the most part, but then when they need to move quickly or ascend, they simply jump and float to where they need to go or grab onto one of those handrails.

if the gravity is low enough to float around like they tend to do, how is it that they can walk on the deck?

Comment: There are times in other series where they use rotating sections or magnetic floors to make it look like they're walking normally. Did Zeta have anything like those?

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing scenes when they are in space and when they are in earth?

Also if you had one of those handrails, would you use it? Like an a electric staircase on the mall.